# Failed to mount /dev/sda1 as root file system in debian

Tags: debian, initramfs

`mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /root failed: Input/output error. Failed to mount /dev/sda1 as root file system`
How can I solve this problem? I'm new with debian. Before this it has showed GUI but after several days it be like this.[image]

Comment: your device sda has an I/O error which you almost didn't include in the screenshot ... the drive has probably failed. Get a new drive, re-install debian on it, and restore from backup any important files that were on sda